# android Ndk undefined reference to sigemptsyset

Tags: android, android-ndk, signals

I am cross compiling some native code for android , I am using some linux timer related signal set (sigemptyset) in my code . everything works fine on my PC , When I build  my code using android ndk-build script I am getting the following errors

```
  jni/../src/Timer.cpp:74: undefined reference to `sigemptyset'
  jni/../src/Timer.cpp:75: undefined reference to `__libc_current_sigrtmin'
  jni/../src/Timer.cpp:75: undefined reference to `sigaddset'
  jni/../src/Timer.cpp:86: undefined reference to `sigemptyset'
  jni/../src/Timer.cpp:88: undefined reference to `__libc_current_sigrtmin'
```

I have properly linked all the libraries , but still I get this undefined reference  error .

Which library I have to use to provide refrence  for function realted signal.h  .

Comment: Check for you have included the header files or not and in ndk  use "" instead of <> to include the header files that you created.

Comment: LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true

Comment: thanks LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS = true is worked